# Prevent button stretch when laid out between two others

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android so please excuse the rookie question. I'm trying to layout four buttons -- one on the left, one on the right, one in the center, and the fourth centered between the left and center buttons. The fourth button is stretching and I can't figure out how to avoid this. How do I get the button to maintain the same sizing as the other three?

Here's the layout:[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/photosButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photosButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cameraButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: While its possible to do this with a RelativeLayout, I recommend trying constraintlayout

Comment: @MidasLefko Thanks! I just hit convert to ConstraintLayout and it looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/photosButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photosButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Try this